# Can't uninstall Malwarebytes

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, malwarebytes

I want to delete Malwarebytes files from my Windows 10 pc, but whenever I try to do it shows the action can't be completed as file is open in another program, I also tried Resource Monitor to end process, but as soon as I do so, the screen turns blank (black) and I have to restart it. What's the solution to this?

Comment: Hello, did you try with BCUninstaller? https://www.bcuninstaller.com/

Comment: Nope, is it safe to use?

Comment: [Malwarebytes can't be uninstalled. - Malwarebytes for Windows Support Forum - Malwarebytes Forums](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/285392-resolved-malwarebytes-cant-be-uninstalled/)

Comment: That's a rhetorical question. Unless by "safe" you mean "can I mess something up", then no, as long as you follow the default process there and e.g. you'll remove only likely leftovers, nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Malwarebytes should uninstall fine on a properly operating OS. That it will not uninstall means something is wrong with the OS

Comment: There's a big difference between 'uninstall' & 'delete'. Deleting an app is bad, but trying to delete an antivirus is worse. They're designed to resist all attempts to modify or damage them - otherwise they'd be useless under a real attack.

Answer (score 5):

You're not supposed to ***delete*** program files manually.

If you wish to **uninstall Malwarebytes** you should do it by uninstalling it from the *Programs and Features* list in the computer's Control Panel (see also [here](https://support.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038984753-Uninstall-Malwarebytes-for-Windows)).

If you want to clean it even farther (make sure all is uninstalled) you can use the **Malwarebytes Support Tool** found https://support.malwarebytes.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039023473-Uninstall-and-reinstall-Malwarebytes-using-the-Malwarebytes-Support-Tool (and make sure to choose No when it asks if you want to reinstall in Step 11).

Answer (score -2):

As someone else has mentioned, I would recommend against deleting the files yourself—there are so many hidden files, and there could even be modifications done to your registry.
The malware support tool suggested by Yisroel Tech works just fine, but if you’d like you could get an app whose sole purpose is to completely uninstall software. Personally, I use Ashampoo Uninstaller, I got it a while back for peanuts, but I am positive that there are other similar softwares out there that are free and just as efficient if not more. Hope this provided additional insight (:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).